# Creating a better nav structure for an list

Tags: html-lists, nav

Fellow Stackers,

I was hoping for some advice for a list in a nav on a website, im having a few issues with it, these are,

1) font rendering switching between normal and bold - it shifts the list a pixel, is ther anyway this can be improved?
2) Active menu marker, i have implemented a marker to highlight the category, its not done the best way is there a better way this could be done?

site in question - http://vignettedesign.com.au/test/

Would love to learn and improve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your font, `Quicksand`. Quicksand is a free webfont which you can also get via [Google Fonts (Quicksand)](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aQuicksand). For some strange reason (because it is definitely weird to do this), the navigation `a:hover`CSS changes the font of hovered links from `CustomFive` to `QuickSand`.

The latter can be viewed on the Google Fonts link I included, and I presume in your website the font included is  `Quicksand Light`, which has a pretty bad rendering (like letters missing pixels). [This article](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2011/08/05/free-or-paid-fonts-what-to-choose-and-why/) (in 'Reason 2') briefly explains why some free fonts are not ideal for businesses.

You need to find the line with this CSS in `style.css`:... Then remove the font-family line.
Google Chrome Inspector tells me it is both on lines 1344 and 1566 in the file. (you have to replace them both).

```
.main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
  background: #FDFDFD; /* set this to any color you which to appear as "highlight" */
  color: #000; /* change this color if you want your textcolor to change on hover */
  font-family: "Quicksand", Helvetica , Arial;
}
```

NB:

- You defo don't need a plugin to highlight a hovered link, just tweak the CSS.
- It's your choice, but if I were you I would replace the `Quicksand` font altogether with another one (bad readability in all of your navigation items and paragraphs using this font), or at least set its font-weight to 600.
- Extra tip: Your paragraphs are barely readable on my 1920x1080 15:8 inch screen. Consider setting the font-size 2 or 3 pixels more.